# Why won't len(temp_list) update its value in a loop where values of temp_list changes every iteration?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, set, drop

I am trying to create a dataframe `data` which consists of two columns which are `'word'` and `'misspelling'`. I have 5 parts in which I attempt to achieve it which are 1 function, 3 dataframes, and 1 loop.

A function which generate misspellings (got this from Peter Norvig):

```
def generate(word):   
    letters     = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'   
    splits      = [(word[:i], word[i:])     for i in range(len(word)  +1)]   
    deletes     = [L + R[1:]                for L, R in splits if R]   
    transposes  = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:]  for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]   
    replaces    = [L + c + R[1:]            for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]   
    inserts     = [L + c + R                for L, R in splits for c in letters]   
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
```

A dataframe with words to generate the misspelling:

```
wl = ['a', 'is', 'the']

word_list = pd.DataFrame(wl, columns = ['word'])
```

An empty dataframe meant to be filled up in the loop:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['word', 'misspelling'])
```

An empty dataframe meant to temporarily hold the values from the function 'generate' in the loop:

```
temp_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['misspelling'])
```

A loop that will fill up the dataframe `data`:

```
y = 0

for a in range(len(word_list)):
    temp_list['misspelling'] = pd.DataFrame(generate(word_list.at[a,'word']))
    data = pd.concat([data,temp_list], ignore_index = True)

    print(len(temp_list)) #to check the length of 'temp_list' in each loop

    for x in range(len(temp_list)):
        data.at[y,'word'] = word_list.at[a,'word']
    
    y = y + 1
    y = data.index[-1] + 1temp_list.drop(columns = ['misspelling'])
```

What I expected when I check `data` outside of the loop is for it to have a total of 390 rows which is the total of `len(generate('is')) + len(generate('a')) + len(generate('the'))`.

The total of rows in `data` turned out to be 234 which is way less. When I went around to check which variable was not tallying up, it turned out to be `len(temp_list)` which I expect it to update every loop since new values are replacing it.

`len(temp_list)` remains the same which is causing `temp_list['misspelling'] = pd.DataFrame(generate(word_list.at[a,'word']))` to only have the maximum length of `len(generate('a'))` (in which `'a'` is the first value in `word_list`) although the generated misspellings in `temp_list` was different each loop.

I thought adding `temp_list.drop(columns = ['misspelling'])` at the end of the outer loop would reset `temp_list` but it doesn't seem like it resetted `len(temp_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

`temp_list.drop()` with `inplace=False` (which is the default) does not modify the existing dataframe, but returns a new one. However, even if you fix that, it still won’t work, because you would also need to drop the index, and I’m not sure that’s even possible.

I don’t quite understand what you are trying to do (for example, the `for x in ...` loop never uses `x`) but I suspect you might be better off using plain Python lists instead of dataframes.